# Solve recurrence: T(n) = T(n/ logn) + O(1)

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

Can you help me solve this recurrence formula and find out the Big-oh? 
T(n) = T(n/logn) + O(1) 
I've tried recursion tree method but it didn't help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like $k$ iterations of
$n/\ln(n)$
gives about
$n/\ln^k(n)$
so this stops when
$n/\ln^k(n)=1$
or
$k = \ln(n)/\ln(\ln(n))$.